# How can I generate an execution plan from Terraform configuration without connecting to AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform

I'm writing a unit test for a Terraform module, and I would like to confirm that the module produces the execution plan that I expect. However, connecting to Amazon within a test would take too long and require too much configuration of the continuous integration server.

How can I use `terraform plan` to generate an execution plan from my configuration that assumes that no resources exist?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've been considering something similar for a testing framework around Terraform modules and have previously used [Moto](https://github.com/spulec/moto) for mocking Boto calls in Python.

Moto works by monkey patching calls to AWS so only works natively with Python. However it does provide the [mocked backend as a server](https://github.com/spulec/moto#stand-alone-server-mode) running on Flask to be used in a stand alone mode.

That said, I've just tried it with Terraform and while `plan`s seem to work okay a very basic configuration being applied led to this error:

```
* aws_instance.web: Error launching source instance: SerializationError: failed decoding EC2 Query response
caused by: parsing time "2015-01-01T00:00:00+0000" as "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z": cannot parse "+0000" as "Z"
```

I then happened to notice that plans complete fine even when the Moto server isn't running and I'm just using a non existent local endpoint in the [AWS provider](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/).

As such, if you just need plans then you should be able to do this by adding an [`endpoint` block](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/aws/#external_id) that points to localhost like this:

```
provider "aws" {
  skip_credentials_validation = true
  max_retries = 1
  skip_metadata_api_check = true
  access_key = "a"
  secret_key = "a"
  region = "us-west-2"

  endpoints {
    ec2 = "http://127.0.0.1:5000/"
  }
}


resource "aws_instance" "web" {
    ami = "ami-123456"
    instance_type = "t2.micro"
    tags {
        Name = "HelloWorld"
    }
}
```

How you inject that endpoint block in for testing and not for real world usage is probably another question and would need more information in how your tests are being constructed.

Comment: After adding fake credentials to the provider, it worked! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does `terraform plan -refresh=false` do what you want?

I use it to do a "fast plan", without taking the time to refresh the status of all the AWS resources.
Not sure if it actually connects to AWS to do that though.

If you're using a more complicated remote-state setup and that's the part you don't want to configure - you could also try adding an empty tfstate file and pointing to that with the `-state` option.

Comment: Just tried this out of curiosity because I liked the simplicity but without any networking enabled it just hangs for me even with very simple configuration. I'd assume that's trying to get to AWS but without looking deeper it might just be trying to get to the internet for other things. It does slightly speed up the plans though.

Comment: `terraform plan -refresh=false` doesn't seem to work. If I omit an AWS provider section, it prompts for AWS credentials. If I provide a provider section, it checks the credentials and returns the error "InvalidClientTokenId: The security token included in the request is invalid.
 status code: 403, request id: XXX".

Comment: `terraform plan -state=/dev/null` and `terraform plan -state=empty_file.tfstate` don't work, either. They print "Error reading local state: Failed to check for magic bytes: EOF".